# Installing/dual-booting Fedora 17 on existing Windows 7 HDD

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, fedora, multi-boot

I have a 64-bit Windows 7 install as the only partition on a 1 TB HDD, with about 350 GB free.  I would like to install Fedora 17 as a dual-boot option on this system and give it about 100 GB to play with.

If in the Fedora install utility I choose to shrink the Windows 7 partition by 100 GB to give it space, will that cause me to lose my existing Windows 7 data?  And how do I go about setting up dual-boot (with Windows 7 as the default)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If in the Fedora install utility I choose to shrink the Windows 7 partition by 100 GB to give it space, will that cause me to lose my existing Windows 7 data?

Generally, no. However, you should always have a backup of your data so that you can restore it incase something goes wrong.

> And how do I go about setting up dual-boot (with Windows 7 as the default)?

Just follow the install Wizard, there's nothing special to be done to set up dual boot.

Comment: Thank you!  I got it working with a relatively small amount of fuss and am looking forward to learning my way around Fedora.  I haven't worked with any *nix in nearly 20 years so I expect a few things have changed... :)

Comment: @Moose4 cheers. Do ask any questions that you might have over here in  [su].